# using same transaction for EntityFramework and ado.net stored procedure

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to integrate two different pieces of code into using the same transaction. One is Entity Framework on Oracle (using odp.net as driver) and the other is using standard ado.net using odp.net. Both are using the same connection string.

What would be the correct way of achieving this?

I can start the EF transaction by using context.Connection.BeginTransaction() but that gives me back System.Data.Common.DbTransaction.

Can I use that somehow with odp.net directly? I would prefer not to use TransactionScope because of all the difficulties involving DTC.

There are various reasons that I cannot just simply use EF to access this stored procedure (we are using some custom made T4 templates for EF that do not support stored procedure at this time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

Here is what I do:

before using entity framework I do:

```
Context.Connection.Open();
var ts = Context.Connection.BeginTransaction();
```

Then i do stuff with EF objects and call SaveChanges().

For ADO.NET, I do the following (just an example, not production code!):

```
   var conn = ((EntityConnection)dal.Context.Connection).StoreConnection;

   var cmd2 = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd2.CommandText = "insert into tst_rob values ('3')";
   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The catch was in casting the Context.Connection to EntityConnection to be able to get to the underlying connection.

at the end I do either ts.Commit() or ts.Rollback(). Voila, no DTC involved and all on the same transaction.